# passing an integer and an array of integers to a VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pass an integer and an array of integers to a function to check whether the integer is a member of the array.The arrowed line gives a compile error msg as: "expect:= ".

```
Public Sub mainSub()
B = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
ckArr(4,B) '<-------
End Sub

Public function ckArr(N As Integer, A() As Integer)
For i = 0 To UBound(A)
If N = A(i) And i <= UBound(A) Then
    Debug.Print N; " Is in the List"
    Exit For 'Do
ElseIf i < UBound(A) Then GoTo NXT
Else:
    Debug.Print N; " Is NOT in the List"
    Exit For 'Do
End If
NXT:
'i = i + 1
Next 'Loop
End function
```

Answer (score 5):

To call a function either use:

```
a = func(b,c)
```

or if you are not interessted in the result do:

```
call func(b, c)
```

or

```
func b, c
```

Doing

```
func(b,c)
```

is **not valid**.

---

So in your particular case, it would be:

```
Public Sub mainSub()  
  B = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
  Call ckArr(4,B) '<-------
End Sub
```

or

```
Public Sub mainSub()  
  B = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
  ckArr 4, B '<-------
End Sub
```

Comment: @musayusuf: You are welcome. If like the answer feel free up upvote it and if you even think it is the answer to your question you can accept it by clicking the answer's white check mark.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
Public Sub mainSub()
    Dim IsMember As Boolean
    b = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

    Dim checkVariable As Integer
    checkVariable = 4
    IsMember = ckArr(checkVariable, b)

    If IsMember Then
    MsgBox checkVariable & " is a member of member of array"
    Else
    MsgBox checkVariable & " is not a member of member of array"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function ckArr(N As Integer, A As Variant) As Boolean
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)

        If N = A(i) Then
            ckArr = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

[image]

`B = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`
so `B` is variant here.

So i have made parameter of below procedure as variant.

From
`Public function ckArr(N As Integer, A() As Integer)`

To
`Public Function ckArr(N As Integer, A As Variant) As Boolean`

Comment: Superb! I ve great admiration for this answer. My poor knowledge of function call is exposed. In addition, how to avoid use of "goto" is is illustrated. Thanks alot.

Comment: @musayusuf I'm Glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 2):

Declaring B as integer Array

```
   Public Sub mainSub()

        Dim B(0 To 5) As Integer
        B(0) = 4
        B(1) = 5
        B(2) = 6
        B(3) = 7
        B(4) = 8
        B(5) = 9

        ckArr 4, B
    End Sub

    Public Function ckArr(N As Integer, A() As Integer)
        For i = 0 To UBound(A)
            If N = A(i) And i <= UBound(A) Then
                Debug.Print N; " Is in the List"
                Exit For    'Do
            ElseIf i < UBound(A) Then GoTo NXT
            Else:
                Debug.Print N; " Is NOT in the List"
                Exit For    'Do
            End If
    NXT:
            'i = i + 1
        Next    'Loop
    End Function
```

Comment: If you are doing a for statement to Ubound of the array, why do you check if you are within the bounds of the array in your code? Also, using Fro i = lBound(A) would be safer than assuming the array starts with element 0.

Comment: @Issun A very good point highlighted. Here i have only made some changes `mainSub` procedure to get the code working. My alternate answer does take of this issues.